# How do I declare a custom comparison function of priority_queue

Tags: c++

I had task about rearrange an array so that the closest numbers to the value `k` will be at the higher priority in `priority_queue`.

I had try this code, but it seems like I have no where to put the parameters:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <queue>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
bool cmp(int a, int b, int k) {
    return (abs(a - k) < abs(b - k));
}
void main() {
    priority_queue<int, vector<int>, decltype(cmp)> a;
}
```

Comment: Which compiler are you using? (Please tag the question to identify.)

Comment: im using c++17;

Comment: `main` needs to return int. `Windows.h` is not required

Answer (score 0):

The `cmp` is a class with an `operator()(int a, int b)->bool`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

struct cmp
{
    bool operator()(int a, int b)
    { 
        return (abs(a - k) < abs(b - k));
    }
    int k = 5;
};

int main() 
{
    priority_queue<int, vector<int>,cmp> a;
}
```